# Vue setTimeout not working with value of variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, settimeout

```js
console.log("Remain: ", remain);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Set timeout remain: ", remain);
}, remain);
```

This is not working!

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Set timeout remain: ", remain);
}, 2000);
```

This is working! After 2s it log that string with remain value.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: where is vuejs?

Comment: What is the expected value of `remain` inside the callback?

Comment: I tried to run the two codes and it return error both. I thought you should provide more code to explain what you want.

Comment: That code snippet is in the mounted of Vue class. I just want to call a function after remain (current timestamp % 30) seconds. But maybe it's not working when I pass variable _remain_ inside the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

This works as intended.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    const remain = 3000;

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('set timeout remain:', remain);
    }, remain);
  },
})
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caseyjoneal/4qstox9L/19/)

Comment: My problem is the `setTimeout` is not working when I pass the value of `remain` variable inside `timeout` param. 
`const remain = 3000;` and `setTimeout(() => {...}, remain);` then it's not working. I execute the body of function inside the setTimeout, not wait `remain` seconds to execute it.

Comment: The code in your comment works as intended. I updated my answer with a working link. Can you share more code so we can see where you're using the `setTimeout`?

Comment: `export default {
  ...
  async mounted() {
    secretKey = "KVKFKRCPNZQUYMLXOVYDSQKJKZDTSRLD";
    if (secretKey) {
      this.generateOtp(secretKey);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    generateOtp(secretKey) {
      const remain = 30 - (~~(Date.now() / 1000) % 30);
      console.log("Remain: ", remain);
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Expect after remain secondes it'll print Set timeout remain: ", remain);
      }, remain);
    }
  }
};`

Comment: You don't need `async mounted` it should just be `mounted`. Aside from having an extra bracket that code works fine. I cannot recreate your issue

Comment: Ah, I know what's problem. Because I set remain without * 1000, so it create timeout in remain milis. Thanks all